# Javascript how to make enter key submit a form

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on n website right now, and I am learning JavaScript along side it. I need to know how to submit the form when the user hits the enter key (Javascript event 13), and makes a new line when enter and shift are clicked. (This question is different from the other questions like this because I need to have it formatted to match my form, because I know very little javascript.) here is the form:

```
<form style="position: absolute; bottom: 5px; padding-bottom: 10px;height:  
10%;" id="newmessageForm">

        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Type your message here" 
rows="9" cols="225" id="newmessage" resize="none" style="float: left;
opacity: 0.7;"></textarea>

        <input class="btn-login" type="Submit" name="send" style="float:
         left">

    </form>
```

thank you for your help!

Comment: This can help you :

 `//to submit your form when press the key 13

    window.onkeypress = function(event) {
       if (event.keyCode == 13) {
          // submit form
          document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
       }
    }`

Comment: would myForm be the name of the form?

Comment: and thank you a lot!

Comment: yes the id of your form newmessageForm

Comment: document.getElementById("newmessageForm ").submit();

Comment: this just refreshes the page...